# "Version" is a type and cannot be resolved

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code :

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "1.6.4 Vanilla Server" Then

        Version = "164"

    End If

    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "1.6.2 Vanilla Server" Then

        Version = "162"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Version As Int16
End Sub
End Class
```

Then I get a blue line under Version saying : Version is a type and cannot be used as an expression

Thanks for any help :/

Comment: thats because `Version` is a type, put it in brackets: `[Version]` or use a different variable name

Comment: @Plutonix                                                              This didn't work :(

Comment: @Plutonix you only need to use brackets for names that are also keywords in VB. Using type names for variables is perfectly fine, perhaps even a best practice.

Comment: Speaking of best practices, declare 16-bit integers as `Short` instead of `Int16`. I might come in and declare my own `Int16` type in the same namespace, causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @StevenLiekens actually brackets work to resolve NET level conflicts too, like a Property Name of Image.  Several warnings will issue about refs to static member will not be evaluated, even though the code will run fine.  Add brackets to the prop dec and the warnings go away.  It was obviously not the solution here though.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of `Version` to `VersionNo`

Edit: declare the variable in  the `Form1` not the `Form1_load`

Use `ME.VersionNo = "162"`, you have declared it as int16 and assigning string to it.

Comment: @user2792832, `Dim VersionNo As String` in form load

Comment: So it does't matter that it isn't declared?

Comment: `Me.VersionNo` would get it from parent. it is already declared in the  `Form1_Load`

Comment: @Tauseef no it's not! `Version` only exists between `Sub Form1_Load` and `End Sub`. The problem is that there is a `System.Version` class, so visual studio thinks you are trying to use that. Which obviously doesn't make sense because you can't assign values to a type.

Comment: @Steven, thats why I suggested him to change the name and use "Me". How ever I ignored that he is iniyializing it in form_load instead of Form

Answer (score 1):

Aaak.  here you go:

```
Public Class Form1
     Private VersionNo As String

... 
Private Sub Button1_Click...
   VersionNo = "164"
   ....
End Sub
```

If you declare it in `Form_Load` it goes out of scope when the sub completes.  you want a module level variable.  When that happened, VB thought you were talking about the Version Type.  If you want to use `Version` you may have to bracket it: `[Version]` to tel VB to use your var, not the NET Type.

Comment: Well, the expansive answer of "doesnt work" hid the fact that the error msg likely changed.